# How to extract a row from a multi dimensional array without numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, sub-array

I'm new to python and for a school project I have to program an AI for the game "connect 4".
My problem is I can't extract a row from a given Grid.

Grid initialization:

```
Grille = [[0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

(Each lines are Columns)

My goal is to initialize an array 'row_array' containing each rows of the given grid, then to initialize another array 'four' containing 4 integers of the 'row_array'.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
row_array = []
    for r in range(6):
        row_array = [Grille[:][r]]
        for c in range(Column_Count-3):
            four = row_array[c:c+4]
```

However in my debug, I've noticed that `row_array` doesn't get the rows of the grid but the columns so at the first iteration, instead of printing:

```
row_array: [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

I get:

```
row_array: [[0,0,0,0,0,1]]
```

Comment: Your multi-dimensional array is just an array of arrays, so, for example, the third row is `Grille[2]` is an array of six items, `[0,0,0,0,0,0]`. If you want a copy of the whole row, use something like `row = Grille[2][:]`.

Comment: You are confusing numpy notation `matrix[:, rownum]` with python, where `matrix[:][2]` behaves like `m = matrix[:]; m[2]`